# Fox Pro Stopped working and OLE error code 0x800a004c

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, ole, foxpro, visual-foxpro

I have modified an old FoxPro application in VFP SP2 and  the final executable(.exe) works fine in my development system. Even in debug mode the application is fine. But when i try running the same build along with the supporting DLLs (got this info after googling) in another system it throws out these errors and the program terminates. However these errors are intermittent.

```
Fatal error: Exception code=C0000005 @ 09/12/14 03:31:07 PM. Error log file: D:\tool\VFP9Rerr.log
Called from -  load line 0  { load.fxp}
Called from -  report line 0  { report.fxp}
Called from -  master line 0  { d:\tool\Tool.exe}
```

**Another Error is:**

```
Exception: 1426 - OLE error code 0x800a004c: Unknown COM status code.
Procedure: master
Line Number:0
```

**And the most Frequent one :**

```
Microsoft Visual FoxPro has stopped Working.
```

Im facing these issues only in other systems. In the Development System it is working good.

Im using Windows 7, 64bit  for both development and testing.

**These are the DLLs i used:**

```
   VFP9RENU.DLL
   VFP9RENU.DLL
   vfp9r.dll
   GdiPlus.dll
   msvcr71.dll
   msvcr100_clr0400.dll
   msvcr110_clr0400.dll
   msvcrt.dll
```

Why is this happening in other systems ?

**Further checking the Events Viewer, i found these error.**

```
Faulting application name: Tool.exe, version: 8.0.2.0, time stamp: 0x47139f24 
Faulting module name: VFP9R.DLL, version: 9.0.0.7423, time stamp: 0x49a31c32 
Exception code: 0xc0000005 
offset: 0x0031ad76 
Faulting process id: 0x17d4 
Faulting application start time: 0x01cfd0cec9e7d5ad 
Faulting application path: D:\tool\Tool.exe 
Faulting module path: D:\tool\VFP9R.DLL 
Report Id: 633e87a9-3cc2-11e4-8b21-54eb6ccd700b
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the responses, the actual cause of the c5 error was the anti virus program installed in TEST systems which were blocking access to certain files. It is  advised only to use virus scanners that allow you to exclude certain files, folders or file types from the scan process. Always exclude DBF, FPT, CDX, DBC, DCT and DCX files.

More info about other causes of C5 can be found [here](http://www.foxite.com/archives/allways-c5-error-running-on-xp-platform-0000037683.htm).

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that the VFP DLLs (VFP9r and VFP9RENU) match the version you built in? You say VFP 9 SP2, but there are also hotfixes that are later. The last version, with all hotfixes is 7423. SP2 without hotfixes is 5815. Make sure that the version you built the EXE with and the DLLs have the same version number.

Comment: The VFP SP2 is 5815 and VFP9r and VFP9RENU are also 5815, the issue is intermittent. Do i have to use GdiPlus.dll, if so which version should i use.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that this is the known problem with opening a form that contains a grid from a menu item of type command? That causes a C5.

Details on this page: http://fox.wikis.com/wc.dll?Wiki~VFP9SP2BugList~Wiki, search for "grid"